# Try defining the operator '[]' flutter firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I used to get data from firestore using this code after an update it shows error

```
return ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
         return PopularShoesTiles(
            name: document.data()['name'],
            imageUrl: document.data()['picture'],
            size: document.data()['size'],
            price: document.data()['price']
          );
        }).toList(),
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You shall use a cast:

```
snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
  return PopularShoesTiles(
    name: data["name"],
    imageUrl: data['picture'],
    size: data['size'],
    price: data['price']
  );
}).toList()
```